# Dynamics CRM - Unable to authenticate to Web API to consume data?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

Probably a duplicate, but as I didn't find exact answer I'm posting this.

I've got credentials for dynamics CRM Web api & I'm using them in my code as  follows:

```
string username = @"user.crm@tmeic.in";
    string password = @"XXXXXXXX";
    string domain = @"tmeictest.crm8.dynamics.com";
    string apiURL = @"https://tmeictest.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/";
```

Then, I'm initialising the client using the method as follows:

```
HttpClient client = GetNewHttpClient(username, password, domain, apiURL);

public HttpClient GetNewHttpClient(string userName, string password, string domainName, string webAPIBaseAddress)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName) });
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIBaseAddress);
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
        return client;
    }
```

I'm calling for the response

```
HttpResponseMessage msg = client.GetAsync(apiURL).Result;
```

But it gives

> unauthorised status 401.

I checked in the browser directly & I'm able to login. But when using it in my code it doesn't authenticate.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question would only work for On-Premise CRMs. I haven't tested below solution but you can give it a try. The client ID below will be the one that you would receive when registering your CRM with AAD. Steps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622431.aspx#App%20registration%20for%20OAuth%20authentication).

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(
    authenticationParameters.Authority, false);

AuthenticationParameters authenticationParameters =
    AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(
        "https://tmeictest.api.crm8.dynamics.com").Result;

var userCredential = new UserCredential(@"user.crm@tmeic.in", @"XXXXXXXX");

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult =
    authenticationContext.AcquireToken(
        authenticationParameters.Resource, @"" /* clientId */, userCredential);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);

HttpResponseMessage msg = client.GetAsync(apiURL).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt770369.aspx#Anchor_3) containing a lot of WebAPI sample code for C#:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Obtains the connection information from the application's configuration file, then 
  /// uses this info to connect to the specified CRM service.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="args"> Command line arguments. The first specifies the name of the 
  ///  connection string setting. </param>
  private void ConnectToCRM(String[] cmdargs)
  {
   //Create a helper object to read app.config for service URL and application 
   // registration settings.
   Configuration config = null;
   if (cmdargs.Length > 0)
   { config = new FileConfiguration(cmdargs[0]); }
   else
   { config = new FileConfiguration(null); }
   //Create a helper object to authenticate the user with this connection info.
   Authentication auth = new Authentication(config);
   //Next use a HttpClient object to connect to specified CRM Web service.
   httpClient = new HttpClient(auth.ClientHandler, true);
   //Define the Web API base address, the max period of execute time, the 
   // default OData version, and the default response payload format.
   httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.ServiceUrl + "api/data/");
   httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
       new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
  }
```